# Password Sync to Office 365 with AAD Connect does not work

Tags: powershell, azure, ms-office, office365, windows-server-2012

I try to sync changed passwords to Office 365. On the beginning with the given tool on Windows 2012 it worked. But when I change a user's password, it does not sync it.

I found a script, often mentioned and so I tried it:

[powershell script](https://unlock-adaccount.blogspot.de/2016/01/force-full-password-sync-with-aad.html)

But it does not help. I also tried

```
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial

Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
```

But nothing changed. I see a "*Full Synchronization*" in "*Synchronization Service Manager*".

Does anyone have an idea how to get that password-sync work?

Comment: Now I think it may never worked. I guess I always set the password as admin online for the new users. So users are synched without password. But for sure password sync in enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I had support from Microsoft now and they solved the issue wich the following lines on powershell:

```
Import-Module ADSync
$aadcon = Get-ADSyncConnector | Where {$_.Type -eq "Extensible2"}
Set-ADSyncAADPasswordSyncState -ConnectorName $aadcon.Name -Enable $True
```

As I understand, the flag to *synchronize password* of *AD Connect* was shows as enabled, but in the background it was not! The script set it manually.

Comment: It came out, it was NOT the solution. It was still not working. The Solution was to uninstall everything inclusive the registry settings and all files on disk and reinstall it with express way. Somewhere it did not realy send the passwords, even everything looked great in the logs etc. Now it realy works. But I had to use the mentioned powershell script (see opening thread) once to do a password sync. But a delta sync works also now.

Answer (score 0):

If your client release is before Feb 2016. Try these commands.

```
Login to the Directory Sync Server
Open PowerShell
Type Import-Module DirSync, and then press ENTER.
Type Start-OnlineCoexistenceSync, and then press ENTER.
```

For the newer client type Get-ADSyncConnectorRunStatus to see what the status is. If it is hung, you can type in Stop-ADSyncSyncCycle to stop it.
You can also try reimporting the module in case the permissions got hosed up by typing Import-Module ADSync , then run your Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta or Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial commands. Do not run one command right after the other without checking the status to make sure it has completed.

Comment: Thanks. I did it, but it does not help.

Comment: Check for errors in Windows application event log. Desciption of errors - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2855271#bookmark-_t2          To get more in depth logging, see this - How to enable debug logging. https://www.messageops.com/software/office-365-password-synchronization/password-synchronization-common-issues-and-questions/#Enable_Debug_Logging